# how to display value if the value is a key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this object but the value has the key element and wondering how to grab the value

**For example:**

```
2:
    values: 123
3:
    values:
        10.0: 456
```

**The code:**

```
 <td>{  agg[2].values}</td>
 <td>{  agg[3].values}</td>
```

**The HTML:**

```
<td>123</td>
<td></td>
```

**The issue:**

I want to display the value "456" in the second "td" but the code is not doing it.

What change I need to do to make the result looks like the below:

```
<td>123</td>
<td>456</td>
```

Comment: Are you using a templating framework? or is this vanilla js?

Comment: Assuming `10.0` isn't constant, this would be `Object.values(agg[3].values)[0]`. But something doesn't add up here because in your example with index `2` you show `values: 123` in the data but `.value` in the code (singular)...

Comment: updated the code it was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming all the keys in the `agg` object are dynamic. Hence, you can try this **:**

```js
const agg = {
  2: {
    values: 123
  },
  3: {
    values: {
      10: 456
    }
  }
};

const arr = [];

Object.keys(agg).forEach(key => {
  if (typeof agg[key].values === 'object') {
    Object.keys(agg[key].values).forEach(innerObjKey => {
        arr.push(agg[key].values[innerObjKey])
    })
  } else {
    arr.push(agg[key].values)
  }
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to use `10.0` as the key. Something like this.

```
 agg[3]["10.0"].value
```

But `10.0` is a weird key, although a valid one.